# Tuple to index using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

It drives me crazy, but I can't figure it out
I have a data matrix of (10000,4)

I need to select some rows where the elements of column 0

```
ind1=np.where( (data[:,0]>55) & (data[:,0]<65) )
```

I want to keep that data only so

```
keep_data=data[ind1,:]
```

But keep_data is now (1,10000,4)

Why is that?

P.S.
What i do is th efollwing

```
keep_data=np.reshape(keep_data,(keep_data.shape[1],keep_data.shape[2]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) returns a tuple.

Therefore, use `ind1 = np.where((data[:,0]>55) & (data[:,0]<65))[0]`

Notice the `[0]` indexing to select the only element of the tuple.

This is noted in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

> **numpy.where**(*condition[, x, y]*)
>
> Return elements, either from x or y, depending on condition.
>
> If only condition is given, **return the tuple** [`condition.nonzero()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html),
>   the indices where condition is `True`.